# jQuery remove array elements if the element value starts with the specified string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript array like

```
["1.A","1.B","1.C","1.D",...,"2.A","2.B",...]
```

Now I want to remove elements from this array by a specified string. For exm if I specify "1" then it should remove all of "1.A","1.B","1.C","1.D"....How to do this in jQuery.

Comment: as has already been stated, the easiest solution is a `map` or `filter` function which removes the offending elements from your array

Comment: @jackwanders: Neither of them remove anything from the original Array. They both create a new Array based on the return value. This can be an issue if there are other references to the original that rely on the modifications.

Comment: @amnotiam `arr = arr.filter(...)` or `arr = $.map(arr,function(){...})`. Just reassign the array to the return value of the function.

Comment: @jackwanders: They reassign the return value to the variable. In JavaScript, arrays are reference types. Any other variables that hold a reference to the original Array will not see the updates. [jsfiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6Mfxe/)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use the native [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function:

```
var array = ["1.A","1.B","1.C","1.D",...,"2.A","2.B",...];
array = array.filter(function(value) {
    return value.indexOf('1') < 0;
});
```

or with jQuery use the [`.grep()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/) method:

```
var array = $.grep(array, function(value) {
    return value.indexOf('1') < 0;
});
```

Comment: `.filter` does not edit the array in-place. As your link points out, it creates a new array with elements that pass the test function

Answer (score 4):

You don't need jQuery to do this--regular JavaScript will do just fine. The code loops through aArray, looks at the first character of the array element with `.substring`, checks to see if it's equal to your specified prefix (in this case `1`) and if it matches, it uses .splice to remove that element from the array:

```
var aArray = ["1.A","1.B","1.C","1.D","2.B","2.C"];

var i = aArray.length;
while(i--) {  
    if ((aArray[i].substring(0,1) == "1") {
       var oRemoved = aArray.splice(i,1);
    }

}
```

Comment: This is the only answer that actually modifies the original Array, which seems to be what OP is asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery map() method to do this:

```
var filter = '1';
origArr = $.map(origArr, function (value, index) {
    if($.inArray(filter, value) != 0) {
        return value;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need jQuery to do this.

```
var data = ["1.A", "1.B", "1.C", "1.D", "2.A", "2.B"];

function removeElements(str) {
    return data.filter(function(a) {
        return (a.indexOf(str + ".") < 0);
    });
}

alert(removeElements(1));
alert(removeElements(2));
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want a function that destructively modifies the original array. Here's one:

```
Array.prototype.removeElementsWithPrefix = function(prefix) {
  for (var i = this.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (this[i].indexOf(prefix) == 0) {
      this.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }
  return this;
}


var a = ["foo", "bar", "baz"];
a.removeElementsWithPrefix("b");
a; // => ["foo"]
```

I don't actually recommend coding a destructive function like this however since a function that copies the original array is safer and more flexible.